# Redis data manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, redis

I have a simple script that loops through a list from a database. I would like to sort this list. How can I sort it by the "year" value?

```
<tbody>
  {{ for(var car in it.carList) { }}
  <tr>
    <td>{{=it.carList[car].make.name}}</td>
    <td>{{=it.carList[car].make.color}}</td>
    <td>{{=it.carList[car].make.year}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{ } }}   
</tbody>
```

Comment: With the `sort()` function perhaps?

Comment: @tadman Please tell me more. Not even sure what language this is. (jquey?)

Comment: Google: "MDN sort" and you get [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: If you can access the database query that fetches the list, you can `ORDER BY year`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function mentioned in the comments, with a custom `compareFunction`.

Replace

```
{{ for(var car in it.carList) { }}
```

with

```
{{ for(var car in it.carList.sort((a, b) => {
    a.make.year - b.make.year;
}) { }}
```

Subtracting two numbers will result in a negative value if the first one is smaller and a positive value if the second one is smaller, which is what `.sort()` is looking for.

Note that this will modify the list *in place*, and it will be sorted if you use it later.

Comment: What about the complexity.

Comment: @akinjide this is the default `Array.sort` function in JavaScript. I don't know what the complexity is, but when you can, you should usually use builtin functions...

Comment: I agree `Array.prototype.sort` optimized and battle tested, but when dealing with `n^2` record, sorting on the view won't scale.

Comment: @akinjide yep, you are correct that sorting on the SQL would be better - I'm answering the question as-is. Here's the specification for `Array.sort`: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort

Comment: And I'm providing an option. Most times providing alternative answers to a question is good.